# PHP: Check if Email Provider is Spam by a List of Text file with file_get_contents

Tags: php, file, email

I'm trying to check If Email of Register User is a Temporary Domain by checking a TXT file List.

```
// LIST.TXT

0-mail.com
0815.ru
0clickemail.com
10minutemail.com
20minutemail.com
30minutemail.com
```

```
// PHP CODE
$getFile = file_get_contents('list.txt');
$email = "email@ofUser.com";

if ($email is in $getFile list) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false!";
}
```

Comment: Use `file` then `in_array` after you strip the `email@`.

Comment: You could also use `strpos` with current code, after you strip the `email@`.